# loopback's User Model (login & logout) methods usage in middleware

Tags: loopbackjs

Is there a way to use the User(model) methods like (login & logout) in our code? Like in my case I want to use the User.login(....) method in the middle-ware that is defined in the route phase of middle-ware.
I tried to import the User model in this way in the middle-ware file.

```
 var loopback = require('loopback');
 var boot = require('loopback-boot');
 var app = module.exports = loopback();

 var User = app.models.user;
```

It gives me the error that "app is undefined".
Kindly let me know is there a way to use the login etc methods in my middle-ware.

Thank you

```
 'use strict';
  var mysql = require('mysql')
  var loopback = require('loopback');
  var boot = require('loopback-boot');
  var app = module.exports = loopback();

  app.start = function() {
  // start the web server
   return app.listen(function() {
      app.emit('started');
   var baseUrl = app.get('url').replace(/\/$/, '');
console.log('Web server listening at: %s', baseUrl);
if (app.get('loopback-component-explorer')) {
  var explorerPath = app.get('loopback-component-explorer').mountPath;
  console.log('Browse your REST API at %s%s', baseUrl, explorerPath);
      }
  });
 };
```

// Bootstrap the application, configure models, datasources and middleware.
// Sub-apps like REST API are mounted via boot scripts.

```
 boot(app, __dirname, function(err) {
 if (err) throw err;
```

// start the server if `$ node server.js`

```
 if (require.main === module)
   app.start(); 
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to bootstrap the application in advance before using the `models`

```
var loopback = require('loopback');
var boot = require('loopback-boot');
var app = module.exports = loopback();

boot(app, __dirname, function(err) {
  // You can start your application here
  app.start();

  // Models have been loaded to app object after boot(). You can use it here if you want
  var User = app.models.user;
});
```

From their [**official document**](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Defining-boot-scripts.html)

> The LoopBack bootstrapper, **loopback-boot**, performs application
>   initialization (also called bootstrapping). When an application
>   starts, the bootstrapper:
>
> - Configures data sources.
> - Defines custom models Configures models and    attaches models to data-sources.
> - Configures application settings
> - Runs boot scripts in the /server/boot directory.

You may want to look at their sample [**server.js**](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/server.js.html) for better reference

Comment: can you please elaborate your answer a little bit more as I am new to loopback, I don't have deeper knowledge about it. thank you

Comment: thank you for your quick response, I have also added the server.js code in my question. kindly check it

Comment: Then you need to use the code inside callback of `boot()` function, `app` object cannot be `undefined` there.